# How to pass a list of independent variable to seaborn and get separate plots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm trying to pass list of column names to seaborn functions in order to make a series of the same plots, but with different independent variables mapped to the same dependent variable. Right now I seem to get them all mapped to the same three subplots.

```
def seaborn_plotter(independent_vs, dependent_v, df):
    plt.figure(figsize=(21,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,3,1)
    ax2 = plt.subplot(1,3,2)
    ax3 = plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    for i in independent_vs:
        sns.boxplot(x=i, y=dependent_v, data=df, ax=ax1)
        sns.countplot(df[i], ax=ax2)
        sns.scatterplot(x=i, y=dependent_v, data=df, ax=ax3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you initiate the figure and axis before the loop.

If you want to make a series of plots you need to either:

- create a figure / axis set in each loop iteration (this creates a separate figure per iteration)
- or create a figure that has enough axis to hold all the plots before the loop and loop trough the axis, e.g. using ax[i] in each iteration

For now I'd just move the fig,ax inside the loop

```
def seaborn_plotter(independent_vs, dependent_v, df):
    for i in independent_vs:
        plt.figure(figsize=(21,7))
        ax1 = plt.subplot(1,3,1)
        ax2 = plt.subplot(1,3,2)
        ax3 = plt.subplot(1,3,3)
        sns.boxplot(x=i, y=dependent_v, data=df, ax=ax1)
        sns.countplot(df[i], ax=ax2)
        sns.scatterplot(x=i, y=dependent_v, data=df, ax=ax3)
```

Comment: Sure. If it solved your problem please accept the answer